# JQuery mobile: initialize a page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have several pages in the same html document. When I open the document in a browser, the first page is shown. The other pages are not initialized, and I would like to know if there is a way to initialize a page without actually showing it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do u mean by "initialized"? All the pages will be initialised at the start, and [you'll be able to access the elements of other pages when the first page inits itself](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/P2XJt/4/).

Comment: Actually they're not. They are initialized the first time they are shown. Before that you can access the dom nodes, but not the widgets.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/RzHDz/

Comment: You mean yiu want to enhance them before showing them? `$('#page id').trigger('pagecreate');`.